# Get libstdc++5 on Raspbian

Tags: cross-compilation, packages, printing

I'm trying to get a semi-old printer driver (lexmark z600) from ubuntu working on my Raspberry Pi.  When I extract the .deb file and poke around in `control` it looks like it's marked Architecture: all, so I thought I'd give it a shot.  However, it fails because it depends on libstdc++5, and `apt-cache search` only gives me libstdc++6.  I tried to find the debian source for this and found [this](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libstdc++5), but I don't see any ARM-related compilations. So, it looks like I need to compile [this guy](https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/gcc-3.3) to ARM, which I'm thinking to make easier I'll do on the Pi itself.  Am I on the right track?  Is there an easier way to get libstdc++5?

Comment: Honestly -- if you intend to try compiling this on the pi, give up now or give up later.  It will take all night, or more likely, half the night then it will crap out for some reason forcing you to figure out why and then start again.  And again.

Comment: So my best bet is to cross-compile on another machine and copy it over? My only other machine is a Windows machine...hmm...

Comment: Set up a virtual machine running Ubuntu or another well known Linux distro and build there.

Comment: I'm honestly telling you to give up now.  You are going to regret having led yourself down a garden path after 8 or 12 hours of screwing around for nothing.  If you can't find a precompiled libstdc++5, just consider that to mean you don't have a driver for this printer.  You do not see the level of difficultly in this, I promise.